# Zoom varies with leaflet in different browsers

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, leaflet

I have been working on a site with leaflet, testing in Chrome in Windows. I've discovered that when I view it in other browsers (specifically Firefox or Chrome on MacOS, IE in Windows, Chrome on Android) the zoom is different: the effect is identical to zooming to 125%, making the zoom inside the map work differently but also making all text etc. appear slightly blurry. If I change the browser zoom to 75% on IE, it looks identical to the Chrome version. [Here's a screenshot with side-by-side comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O46Qv.png).

Here's a simplified version of the code which is producing this problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_dark.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapdiv"></div>
        <script>
            // settings
            var northWestCorner=L.latLng(53.85,-5.48),
                southEastCorner=L.latLng(51.03,-2.44),
                mapBounds=L.latLngBounds(northWestCorner,southEastCorner);
            var mainMap = L.map('mapdiv', {
                maxBounds:mapBounds,
                minZoom:8,
                maxZoom:13
            }).setView([52.16, -3.65], 9);
            
            // create map
            L.tileLayer('http://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            }).addTo(mainMap);
            
        
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
#mapdiv{top:0vh;left:0vw;height:100vh; width:100vw;vertical-align: top;}
body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#mapdiv{padding:1px;}
.text-center {padding:1px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
display: none; 
 }
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: possibly one of your browsers had its zoom altered. try pressing CTRL+0 to both browsers to reset the zoom

Comment: thanks for your comment! i'd tried ctrl+0 - it resets it back to these different states (this is across machines, including mobile).

Comment: okay, my second guess is that some css is being applied only to one of your browser or maybe some css 3's like the vh vw are NOT supported to one of your browsers cough cough internet explorer. use the website http://caniuse.com/ to see what parts of css are working across different browsers and their versions.

Comment: okay, i've checked this and in theory vh and vw are supported in all the browsers i'm using (the scrollbar display isn't, but that's a separate problem). if instead i just set the size in px, i still get the same problem - http://imagebucket.net/g72s2wnj6zi6/screenshot.gif.

however, it is really clear that this is about zoom - now i realise you can actually see that what IE's zoom is, turns out it is on 150% on this and resets to 150% on ctrl+0. i guess the same is happening on chrome on android? is there any way to influence this behaviour?

Comment: try setting in your css `body {zoom:100% !important;}`. Do you have any "reading-enhancer" type of addons installed on your browsers that may automatically interfere with the zoom setting?

Comment: adding zoom and -ms-zoom doesn't change it; i don't have any reading-enhancer addons installed (or barely any addons at all, as i've never used IE on this machine before). i've found that changing the display setting my computer to "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" fixes the IE problem, but I can't find an equivalent on android.. obviously it would also be preferable to be able to fix this in the page, so that i can assume it will work for unknown other users! but i'm starting to realise that may be impossible... thanks again @Sharky for all your help :)

Comment: can you post the contents of that css file `styles_dark.css`?

Comment: at minimum, it just contains the css i posted in the question -

<style>
   #mapdiv{top:0px;left:0px;height:500px; width:500px;vertical-align: top;}
   body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
            body {zoom:100% !important;}
   #mapdiv{padding:1px;}
   .text-center {padding:1px;}
   ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
   }
  
  </style>

that produces the problem